# Vivado 2016.2 Simulator doesn't support System Verilog $cast or $sformatf

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, vivado, test-bench

Using the Vivado 2016.2 simulator I need to cast an int to a string in System Verilog but $cast and $sformatf are not supported. What other functions or methods are available to me in order to successfully typecast an int to a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the following other ways

```
string s;
int i;

s.itoa(i); // converts int to decimal string
$swrite(s,"%d",i);
$sformat(s,"%d",i);
```

If none of those work for you, then you'll need to write a binary to decimal conversion routine yourself.

Comment: $sformat does the job, though it is a little quirky I can make it work for my needs. Thanks!